# Filtering results by calculated distance (from coordinates)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to filter results from by table by only returning "Events" which are in some radius (in Kilometers) but my combination of Stored procedure and function is not working... It returns no results.. If i change return in my function which calculates the distance for example to 5 Km and run stored procedure with higher radius then 5 Km it returns results.. so maybe my function is wrong?

Here is function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCalcDistanceKM](@lat1 float, @lat2 float, @lon1 
float, @lon2 float)
RETURNS FLOAT 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @g geography;
DECLARE @h geography;
SET @g = geography::Point(@lat1, @lon1, 4326);
SET @h = geography::Point(@lat2, @lon2, 4326);
return @g.STDistance(@h);
END
```

And here is SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetEventByDistance]
@Latitude float,   
@Longitude float,  
@Radius int
AS   
with MyCte as
(
    select dbo.fnCalcDistanceKM(l.Latitude, l.Longitude, @Latitude, @Longitude) as distance, a.*, l.Adress, l.City, l.Latitude, l.Longitude, l.PSC
    from dbo.Events a 
    JOIN Locations as l ON l.Id = a.LocationId
)
SELECT MyCte.Adress, MyCte.City, MyCte.Description, MyCte.Doporuceno, MyCte.EndDate, MyCte.Id, MyCte.Latitude, MyCte.LocationId, MyCte.Longitude, MyCte.Name, MyCte.ProvozovatelId, MyCte.PSC, MyCte.StartDate, MyCte.TypAkce
From MyCte
where distance < @Radius
RETURN 
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for every answer! :)

Comment: Sorry for some czech verbs in row names

Comment: Your function takes the parameters in this order: `lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2` - but it looks like your procedure is passing them in the order `lat, lon, lat, lon`. Please let us know if this resolves your issue, in which case this question should be closed/deleted as a "simple typographical error".

Comment: @santi Thanks man.. been struggling in this for hours.. i totally missed this mistake.. and the second mistake was that i was expecting kilometers but SRID 4326 returns meters so i had to divide it by 1000 and now it's working! Thanks a lot man :)